# sql divide by zero error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an equation

```
((P.RealisedConsumption / (NULLIF((PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO), 0) 
    / NULLIF(1000000, 0))) - 1) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
```

This works for the example order that I am looking at.  However if i take out the where clause (so i have all orders) i get divide by zero error.

If I limit the / 1000000 to 10 which i then have

```
((P.RealisedConsumption / (NULLIF((PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO), 0) 
    / NULLIF(10, 0))) - 1) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
```

This works for all orders, but is incorrect I need to divide by a million.  How can I get this to work?   The columns are `numeric(32, 16)`.

Comment: What data types are the fields ?  You likely need to convert the divisor to a decimal type.

Comment: Please show the entire T-SQL `SELECT` statement, since it is difficult to tell what the problem is without seeing the entire thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I ended up doing this... this resolved my issue...

```
CASE WHEN (PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO / 1000000) <> 0 THEN
    ( P.RealisedConsumption / ( PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO / 1000000 ) - 1 ) * 100 
END AS FibreScrapFactor
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your data types are already decimal types, perhaps you need to remove NULL values with a `WHERE` clause instead of coalescing them to `0`, which would result in the "divide by zero" error.

Something like:

```
SELECT ((P.RealisedConsumption / (NULLIF((PO.ActualQty * P.QuantityPO), 0) 
    / NULLIF(10, 0))) - 1) * 100 AS FibreScrapFactor
FROM  <...>
WHERE PO.ActualQty IS NOT NULL
    AND P.QuantityPO IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: the datatypes are all numeric(32, 16)

Comment: But do they allow NULLs or not?

Comment: Presumably they do, otherwise why use NULLIF?